# Factorization of Gauss integers

Tags: ring-theory, factoring, prime-factorization, unique-factorization-domains

How do I find the factorization in prime elements of $20538 - 110334i$ in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$? I have found that $20538=2×3^2×7×163$ and $110334=2×3×7×2627$ but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: How did you find the prime factors of the two integers in Z? Factorization in Z[i] works the same way as factorization in Z, so you can use the same technique.

Comment: I simply computed it

Comment: But /how/? Surely if I say “simply compute the factorization” that’s not going to be a helpful answer to you.

Comment: I verified if each number divides with some primes

Comment: Why not use the same technique, except with primes in the Gaussian integers?

Comment: Hint. Factor out the common rational integer factors ($2, 3, 7$), factor those separately when possible. Then factor (in the rational integers) the norm of what remains. You'll need to know about how primes congruent to $1$ mod $4$ split in the Gaussian integers.

Comment: @StellaBiderman:  Many people know the list of primes in $\Bbb Z$ so can factor by trial division.  Many of those, including me, do not know the primes in $\Bbb Z[i]$ so cannot do the computation as simply.

Comment: the result should be $$\left( i \right)  \left(  \left( 1+i \right)  \right) ^{3} \left( -3
 \right)  \left( -7 \right)  \left(  \left( 1+2\,i \right)  \right) ^{
3} \left(  \left( -3+2\,i \right)  \right) ^{4}
$$

Comment: There is a result that if an integer in $\Bbb{Z}$ is prime and $\equiv 1\
 (\text{mod }4)$, then it factorises in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. E.g. $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. However, if the integer is prime and $\equiv 3\ (\text{mod }4)$, then it doesn't factorise in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$, so $3$ doesn't factorise in $\Bbb{Z}[i]$. Also, note that $2=(1+i)(1-i)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the factors $2\times 3 \times 7$ which you know. Note that one of these is not prime in your context, so there is more work to do (I assume you know what happens to integer primes in $\mathbb Z[i]$)

You are left with $489-2627i$.

Consider $(489-2627i)(489+2627i)=239,121+6,901,129=7,140,250$

Every prime factor of $489-2627i$ will be a prime factor of $7,140,250$ as will its complex conjugate. So you should be able to determine candidate factors by factorising in $\mathbb Z$ to start with. You then need to test whether it is the factor or its conjugate which is a factor of your original number.

Answer (score 1):

$a+bi\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is prime if one of the following holds:

1. One of $a$ and $b$ is zero and the other is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$ that is $3$ mod $4$.
2. $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$.

You can use this to find all the prime of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and apply any technique that works for factoring integers except with this new list of primes to factor numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

You can also use properties of the norm. $N(xy)=N(x)N(y)$ and $x|N(x)$ for every $x,y$. If you have $x\in\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and you factor it’s norm into primes, you can look at the numbers whose norm is those primes.